# Failed to (compile &) link several f90 programs containing openMPI

Tags: ubuntu, gfortran, openmpi

I have a problem compiling several .f90-programs containing openmpi.
When trying to compile the programs using `mpifort`, creating the `.o`-files seems to be no problem, but creating the executable fails.
The "warnings" are undefined references to `»mpi_address_«` and `»mpi_type_struct_«` (just these two).
The makefile I use looks like this:

```
all:$(EXE)

%.o:%.f90 input_parameters.h
    $(FC) $(DFLAGS) $(FCFLAGS) -c  $< $(MPILNFLAGS) -o $@

$(EXE):$(OBJ) 
    $(FC) $(DFLAGS) $(FCFLAGS) $(MPILNFLAGS) -o  $(EXE) $(OBJ)
```

and

```
MPICFLAGS = $(shell mpifort --showme:compile)
MPILNFLAGS = $(shell mpifort --showme:link)
```

Someone has an idea what to do?

PS: for example one `mpifort` line looks like this:

```
mpifort -D_MPI_ -I/usr/local/include -pthread -O3 -w  -g -c  file_name.f90 -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi -o file_name.o
```

Comment: These symbols were removed from the standard, and (accidentally) removed from Open MPI 4 by default. You can rebuild Open MPI with `--enable-mpi1compatibility`, wait for 4.0.1 or modernize your code (e.g. `MPI_Get_address()`). On the long run, the latter option is the best (and likely the only one).

Comment: Worked with that, thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet i took the liberty to convert your comment to an answer - which it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

These symbols were removed from the standard, and (accidentally) removed from Open MPI 4 by default. You can rebuild Open MPI with `--enable-mpi1compatibility`, wait for 4.0.1 or modernize your code (e.g. `MPI_Get_address()`). On the long run, the latter option is the best (and likely the only one).